# How to read pdf which is in document directory in iPhone using swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, pdfviewer

As I am new to swift and iOS, I am working on a app where I need to read the content of the PDF and populate on the viewcontroller(textlabel), please let me know how to do it using swift

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read more about [CGPDFDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFDocumentGetPage)

A quick snippet that will get the number of pages of the PDF

```
var pdfDoc: CGPDFDocumentRef!
var numberOfPages: Int = 0
let pdfURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myPDFDocument", withExtension: "pdf")
pdfDoc = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(pdfURL)
numberOfPages = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDoc) as Int
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, Can you please help me how to retrieve the content from that pdf file.

Comment: Thanks for the information, Can you please help me how to retrieve the content from that pdf file